# QGraphicsPathItem antialiazing problem

Tags: qt, line

I use QGraphicsPathItem when draw line on scene. But lines on the scene not exactly straight.Line is knurled.

I searched but there isnt QGraphicsPathItem anitialising property. Do you have any suggestion about this?

Answer (score 3):

You would use [`QGraphicsView::setRenderHint(QPainter::RenderHint)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html#setRenderHint) on your view with [`QPainter::Antialiasing`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainter.html#RenderHint-enum) flag as an argument.

For example:

```
myView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

If you are not satisfied with the results, then you can try this: [`setViewport(QWidget*)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewport)to [`QGLWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qglwidget.html) and turn on the [`QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainter.html#RenderHint-enum) render hint.

```
myView->setViewport(new QGLWidget);
myView->setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
```

Comment: I use this but lines color get dull. Is there another solution?

Comment: You can try using QGLWidget as your viewport and set QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing, but I am not sure if the results will be any better.